# How do I send the data from a form to my company mail?

Tags: php

I want to make a form for users and in that form i want to be  name, tel and email. And i want to make a script that should take the name, tel and email and sent to my emai. But i don t know how and where should i put the php code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: want to send email in magento 2?

Comment: where you want to display this form

Comment: I made a page for users who want to cancel the order, and on that page I put a form. And the data from that form I want to send them to my mail.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hl6ebKO_EKs&t=460s        Something like this

Comment: On my site i want to display. but i dont know how can i add  <?php      ?>   code

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this way for learning a how extension works,and how to send a mail on form submit.
please download this extension and install in your project and learn about it :

[Extesnion Link](https://marketplace.magento.com/ranosysmage-module-prodinquiry.html)